# Two-stage clustering in R

Tags: r, clustering

- Is it possible to do 2-stage cluster analysis in R?
- Can anybody provide me resource on it?

Comment: You mean like clustering on a sample to quickly get good starting centroids for the 'full' pass?  Or more like two different methods altogether?

Comment: Are you referring to the clustering algorithm which SPSS calls two-step? http://www.spss.ch/upload/1122644952_The%20SPSS%20TwoStep%20Cluster%20Component.pdf

Comment: Yeah! I'm taking about spss kind of 2-step clustering.But I want to do it using R.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest package that I can think of is [birch](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/birch/), but it is not available on CRAN anymore so you have to get the source and install it yourself (`R CMD install birch_1.1-3.tar.gz` works fine for me, OS X 10.6 with R version 2.13.0 (2011-04-13)). It implements the original algorithm described in

> Zhang, T. and Ramakrishnan, R. and
>   Livny, M. (1997). [BIRCH: A New Data
>   Clustering Algorithm and Its
>   Applications](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.93.2882&rep=rep1&type=pdf). *Data Mining and
>   Knowledge Discovery*, *1*, 141-182.

which relies on cluster feature tree, as does SPSS TwoStep (I cannot check, though). There's a possibility of using the k-means algorithm to perform clustering on `birch` object (`kmeans.birch()`), that is partition the subclusters into k groups such that the sum of squares of all the points in each subcluster to the assigned cluster centers is minimized.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chl! It seems to be a very rare package as I didn't come across it after doing huge amount of searches.

Comment: @user4278 I also found some hits with Weka (e.g., [here](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc/weka/datagenerators/BIRCHCluster.html)) but I didn't look further.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this also can help: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/prcr/

> Provides an easy-to-use yet adaptable set of tools to conduct person-center analysis using a two-step clustering procedure. As described in Bergman and El-Khouri (1999) `doi:10.1002/(SICI)1521-4036(199910)41:6%3C753::AID-BIMJ753%3E3.0.CO;2-K`, hierarchical clustering is performed to determine the initial partition for the subsequent k-means clustering procedure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But it's 8 years ago. I guess it will be useful for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something akin to a 2-step, have you considered looking into Self Organizing Maps. I think it is based on similar (but not the same) principle as 2-step.