# Hierarchical clustering of categorical variables in R - alternative algorithms / tools

Tags: clustering, categorical-data, hierarchical-clustering

I am running a hierarchical clustering process in `R`, using `daisy`to compute a dissimilarity matrix and `agnes` for hierarchical clustering, as described in [Clustering of mixed type data with R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24540/categorical-variables-clustering-with-r).

With my 8 GB Ram, I constantly run into this error:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.8 Gb
```

I have 21836 rows with only 2 variables. However, I'd like to use more variables, but I am already running out of memory using only 2.

- Are there any alternative algorithms for a mixed data set of
  continuous and categorical variables?
- Are there any alternative tools (I am currently using R) which would
  require less memory?

Comment: You are clustering rows, so the size of the matrix is `21836^2`. Multiply by 8 and you'll get roughtly 4 Gb RAM needed _only to store_ the input matrix. But the procedure (and computer) surely needs more free memory to be able to perform. I'm not R user, though, so please wait for somebody knowing R well to advise you.

Comment: Besides, I'm sceptical about the idea itself - to cluster so many objects by hierarchical cluster analysis (see last point [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/63549/3277)).

Comment: Thx for sharing your thoughts. Do you have sth  in mind how to solve this issue?

Comment: When I have to cluster very many objects by categorical (nominal) variables I use Two-step clustering of SPSS (I'm SPSS user).

Comment: What algorithm do you apply there?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/81603/3277

Comment: @ttnphns judging from the error message, the full distance matrix is 1.8 GB "only" (probably exploiting symmetry, 21835 * 21834 / 2 * 8. But R maybe makes too many copies and thus runs out of memory even with 8GB RAM.